# Cannot participate in Skype group calls

Tags: 14.04, skype

So whenever someone calls the whole group(about 9 people in it) It doesn't get me into the call.
Neither can I join the call when its started.
It was working fine until about a month ago...

Does anyone know how to fix it?
I tried reinstalling Skype, renaming the .Skype directory, installing from .deb and from terminal, stil doesn't work....

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/804051/skype-group-chats-are-not-showing/804144?noredirect=1#804144

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft hasn't updated Skype for Linux for a long time and it no longer works. I'm not sure if a fix will be released.

Comment: I certainly hope they will release a fix for it...

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem at work recently, and we found a few workarounds :

**Fix 1**

Close Skype

In a terminal, type :

```
rm -rf ~/.Skype
```

(this removes your whole Skype config, so be sure you know your login and password)

relaunch Skype

**Fix 2**

In a Skype chat window, type :

```
/dumpmsnp
```

If the output is :

```
System: MSNP: Connection Data:

 * Status: LoggedOut
```

Then type :

```
/msnp24
```

And restart Skype.

The dumpmsnp command output should look like this :

```
SNP: Connection Data (MSNP24):
* Status: LoggedIn
* Server Current: XXXXXXXXXXX.gateway.messenger.live.com
* Server Saved: s.gateway.messenger.live.com
* Login: (UIC)
* Skypename: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
* EPID:
* ClientVersion:
* OSVersion:
* B:
* Time: TZ:
* Last Connect:
* Push: None (Unregistered)
```

**Fix 3**

Close Skype

In a terminal, type :

```
grep Home ~/.Skype/*/config.xml
```

The output should be similar to :

```
    <HomeServer>s.gateway.messenger.live.com</HomeServer>
```

If this line is present but with another server, try replacing it with this server and relaunch Skype

If this line is missing, edit the config.xml file with your favorite text editor, and look for a  section.
Add it, or replace it if it's already here, with this :

```
    <MSNPCore>
      <HomeServer>s.gateway.messenger.live.com</HomeServer>
      <NewThreadAllowed>1</NewThreadAllowed>
      <P2PMigrationAllowed>0</P2PMigrationAllowed>
      <ProtocolToUse>24</ProtocolToUse>
      <RecentConnectionInfo></RecentConnectionInfo>
      <RecentConversationsSyncState></RecentConversationsSyncState>
    </MSNPCore>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, did all the fixes, hopefully they work, havent tested them yet (fingers crossed)

Comment: This didnt work.... I still cannot join group calls.