# Skype group chats are not showing

Tags: 14.04, skype

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and Skype 4.3.0.37. I've a premium account in Skype.

For last two days I'm experiencing an issue. I'm not getting any chat text from the Skype groups I'm added to. Though I'm getting chat text from individual contacts. As well as if I create new skype group and add other persons from my contact then I'm getting the chat texts but if someone adds me in a new group then also I'm not getting the texts. Another thing is, though my status in Skype is online still everybody in my contact list is seeing my status as away.

I've already tried reinstalling the Skype app but the same issue is still there.

Comment: As Skype is a proprietary software, only they can help you with it. Also take I'm mind the Linux version of Skype may miss some of the latest features of Windows and Mac versions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for support of a proprietary third-party software.

Comment: @DavidFoerster All due respect, but how is asking how to do something under Ubuntu 14.04 off topic? Certainly there must be some way...

Comment: @ElderGeek: The question looked like it came down to a bug report against proprietary third-party software. Alas there are some useful answers as to why it doesn't work and possible workarounds so I'm retracting my vote.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I understand. I thank you and the community thanks you!

Answer (score 3):

Skype group chats will not work on the current version of Skype (It is a [known bug](https://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Skype-group-chat-not-working-anymore/td-p/3987288) reported on their forums for Linux users & [other places](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/02/skype-for-linux-group-calls-need-to-update-issue)). You can voice talk, but typing something or having actual access to the chat will not work.

With that said, the [Skype for Linux (Alpha Version)](https://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Skype-for-Linux-Alpha-and-calling-on-Chrome-amp-Chromebooks/td-p/4434299) will work (Confirmed by me). You can send text, images and other normal stuff done on the chat (Be it 1 to 1 or group chat). The options you get are **"Send Photos and Files"** and **"Send Contacts"**. I have uploaded an image where you can also see a group of 8 I was chatting on while also having the option to upload (Using Ubuntu 16.04)

Note that, although it says "Alpha" it works much better and has more features than the "Current" version found on Ubuntu 16.04 and previous versions. Each incremental update to Skype in the past was simply making things worse. The Alpha version is here to solve all issues (I hope).

[image]

**Using Skype Alpha with Current Skype 4.X on Linux will not work** as pointed by Pilot6. If the Alpha user calls, the Current Skype Linux User will never get the call. If the Current Skype Linux user call the Alpha, the Alpha user will get the following message:

`This person tried to contact you but there was a problem connecting the call, try calling them back.`

This is because Skype Linux 4.3 clients always use p2p and the Alpha version does not support this. Because of this you cannot establish a call between Skype 4.3 clients and Skype for Linux Alpha.

Comment: The problem with Alpha is that it can't communicate with the regular version of Skype for Linux.

Comment: @Pilot6 Actually I communicate just fine with the alpha version. No problems at least from my case with users on Windows or Linux. For Ubuntu users I tested with 2 other members and for Windows users I tested with clients. But if the Ubuntu users also have the alpha version there won't be any problems at least from my tests (I only tested alpha to alpha). Would not make since to stay on the "current" one with so many issues and opting out of the alpha which works better.

Comment: I read that communication alpha to stable on linux does not work. Alpha to alpha works.

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes, give me a moment to do the testing. I'll be back with results

Comment: It will be good to test, but I read it from the official source. But I can't find the link now.

Comment: @Pilot6 finished testing. It does not work with the 4.x version on Linux, only with Alpha. Excellent work Pilot6

Comment: Bravo! It's great to see good answers to a proposed closed question! Thanks for sorting out the facts on this one guys!

Answer (score 2):

You can start a group video call from [Skype](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34630/group-video-calling-with-skype) on:

```
   Windows
    Android
    iOS
    Mac
    Skype for Web
```

Notably missing from this list is any flavour of Linux client which leaves out Ubuntu. Rather than giving up you could try:

A) Running the Windows version under Wine or under Windows installed on Virtual Box.

B) [Skype for Web](https://blogs.skype.com/tag/skype-for-web/) Which is reported to  work from any computer.

C) Another possibility as pointed out by @edwinksl is  [Skype For Linux Alpha.](https://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Skype-for-Linux-Alpha-and-calling-on-Chrome-amp-Chromebooks/td-p/4434299) It's not reported as fully functional as of now, but that could change.

Comment: I suspect [Skype for Linux Alpha](https://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Skype-for-Linux-Alpha-and-calling-on-Chrome-amp-Chromebooks/td-p/4434299) may work too.

Comment: @edwinski Nice find. If you don't mind I'll edit that into the answer

Comment: Oh definitely, please do. Caveat though is that I haven't tried it myself, so I can't confirm that it really works.

Comment: @edwinksl My apologies for the misspelling of your name. thank you for fixing that. I'll go find my glasses now.... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same problem and I found the solution in Skype forum:

To check your connection status, type the following commands in any chat window

- `/dumpmsnp` – show details about your connection
- `/showplaces` – show where you are currently connected

What was happening was that `/dumpmsnp` command was showing `LoggedOut`, but I was online and talking almost normally (except group chats).

```
System: MSNP: Connection Data:
 * Status: LoggedOut
```

To solve this `LoggedOut` issue, try this on any chat window:

```
/msnp24
```

and restart your Skype.
After restarting, `/dumpmsnp` output shows the following status:

```
System: MSNP: Connection Data (MSNP24):
 * Status: LoggedIn
```

This, solved my problem, it showed the chat window and I bookmarked it for ease. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the other solutions:

You might be marked as "away" because you are logged in on your phone, which will set your status as "away" all the time.